# how to code search interface in android

Tags: android

I am making an android app to store the images along with text to server and than fetch them to view images as well as their description. Now for user simplicity i put a search bar in activity where i display these images.I successfully put a search bar at activity bar but the problem is that i don't know how to make a search interface for item search in search bar.
  My XML code is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtSearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my activity code in which i put the search bar.

```
package com.manali.vivek.userregistration;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

//Creating a List of superheroes

private List<buysecBook> listsecBook;

//Creating Views
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

String DATA_URI;

//Volley Request Queue
private RequestQueue requestQueue;

//The request counter to send ?page=1, ?page=2  requests
private int requestCount = 1;

//// toolbar
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private MenuItem mSearchAction;
private boolean isSearchOpened = false;
private EditText edtSeach;
/////toolbar


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.progress_layout);



    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);


    /////// toolbar

    //Initializing Views
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    //Initializing our superheroes list
    listsecBook = new ArrayList<>();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Calling method to get data to fetch data
    getData();

    //Adding an scroll change listener to recyclerview
   recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int
  newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            getData();
        }
    });

    //initializing our adapter
    adapter = new CardAdapter(listsecBook, this);

    //Adding adapter to recyclerview
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

//Request to get json from server we are passing an integer here
//This integer will used to specify the page number for the request ?page =
  requestcount
//This method would return a JsonArrayRequest that will be added to the
request queue
private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {
    //Initializing ProgressBar
    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) 
findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    //Displaying Progressbar
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    //JsonArrayRequest of volley
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(DATA_URI +
  String.valueOf(requestCount),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                    parseData(response);
                    //Hiding the progressbar
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //If an error occurs that means end of the list has  
   reached
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "No More Items Available",
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    //Returning the request
    return jsonArrayRequest;
}

//This method will get data from the web api
private void getData() {
    //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer
    requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));
    //Incrementing the request counter
    requestCount++;
}

//This method will parse json data
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        //Creating the superhero object
        buysecBook buysecBook = new buysecBook();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            //Getting json
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding data to the superhero object
            buysecBook.setImageUrl(json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
            buysecBook.setbookName(json.getString(Config.TAG_BOOKNAME));


 buysecBook.setphoneNumber(json.getString(Config.TAG_PHONENUMBER));
            buysecBook.setPrice(json.getString(Config.TAG_PRICE));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Adding the superhero object to the list
        listsecBook.add(buysecBook);
    }

    //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX,
 int oldScrollY) {
    //Ifscrolled at last then
    if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
        //Calling the method getdata again
        getData();
    }
}

//This method would check that the recyclerview scroll has reached the
 bottom or not

 private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
        int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)
  recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && 
  lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}



public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main2, menu);
    return true;
}


 ////// toolbar

public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    mSearchAction = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_search:
            handleMenuSearch();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


protected void handleMenuSearch(){
    ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar(); //get the actionbar

    if(isSearchOpened){ //test if the search is open

        action.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false); //disable a custom view 
inside the actionbar
        action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true); //show the title in the
 action bar

        //hides the keyboard
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
  getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edtSeach.getWindowToken(), 0);

   mSearchAction.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.
      drawable.ic_open_search));



        isSearchOpened = false;
    } else { //open the search entry

        action.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); //enable it to display a
        // custom view in the action bar.
        action.setCustomView(R.layout.search_bar);//add the custom view
        action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //hide the title

        edtSeach =
  (EditText)action.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.edtSearch); 

              edtSeach.setOnEditorActionListener(new 
   TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent
   event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    doSearch();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        edtSeach.requestFocus();

        //open the keyboard focused in the edtSearch
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
  getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(edtSeach, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);


        //add the close icon

  mSearchAction.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.
   drawable.ic_close_search));

        isSearchOpened = true;
    }
}


public void onBackPressed() {
    if(isSearchOpened) {
        handleMenuSearch();
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}

private void doSearch() {
    //write code for what u want to do
}


 }
```

Comment: Could you please post the required code only. It will support us to read your question fast and you can have the answer quickly.

Comment: I suppose you are storing your images in a database. Have you already written the code that will insert and search for the images ?

Comment: I just wanted to know what should i write in private void doSearch() method to show my search result